# Overlay Text on an Image in Android

Tags: android, textview, screen-size

I would like to know if there is a way to overlay text on an image in Android and cater for various different screen sizes? Currently I simply use the image as the background image to the layout and then I just use textview's over that.

The problem I have is that when the image is scaled on another device with a smaller or bigger screen, the position of this text changes and it looks different since the text does not scale the same way the image does on a different device, even though I use DP to position the textview's.

Is there some way to anchor these textview's to a certain point on the screen so that it looks more or less the same on different screen sizes?

Comment: Simply set the image as the background for your TextView. And align the text properly (top, bottom, center, ...).

Comment: If I onderstand it correctly, you want your textsize to scale with the imagesize? Have a look at this: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview You can now align this textview to where you want on your imageview and text will scale as imageview scales.

Comment: You can also use a relative layout and do something like this

Answer (score 0):

**Check this. this Xml will work well in any Device.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/advrttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center Text in any Device"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a relative layout and do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/uninorsample"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example_Txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example Text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView12"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set image as background in any widget or layout than set textview on that with appropriate dimension.i.e you can set shadow image in relative layout and set textview on it use property like centerinparent so it will always center of the parent in any DP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/clock_number"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Overlayed Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```